# PHP convert Variable holding a 24 hour time to 12 hour

Tags: time

I have a variable from the database

```
$time = $row['pu_eta'];  //13:00
```

I now need to convert it to: 12 hour format.

Trying this has not succeeded.  Any help would be most appreciated.

$time = format(strptime($time, format('%H:%M'), '%I:%M %p');

Answer (score 0):

I found after extensive searching I was able to find a solution.  I hope it's helpful to you too.

```
$row['pu_eta'] = "13:00";

$time = date_create($row['pu_eta']);
$time2 = date_format($time, "h:ia");

echo $time2;  //01:00pm
```